# How can I add members to a rapidjson document using integers as the key/name?

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm using a for loop and want to use the iterator, i, as the key/name when I add a member to the document. For example I want the document to look like this:

{"1":"123.321","2":"456.654"}

Here is what I have tried so far.

**1. Converting i to a const char***

```
rapidjson::Value newDouble(6);
for(int i = 0;i<laserScan.size();i++){
    newDouble.SetDouble(laserScan[i]);
    const char* index = std::to_string(i).c_str();
    d.AddMember(index,newDouble,d.GetAllocator());
}
```

This generates a compiler error telling me that AddMember can only take arguments of type rapidjson::GenericValue&:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<> >::AddMember(const char*&, rapidjson::Value&, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>&)’
     d.AddMember(index,newDouble,d.GetAllocator());//add this name-value pair to the JSON string
```

**2. Converting i to a string using rapidjson types**

```
rapidjson::Value newDouble(6), newStringIndex(5);
for(int i = 0;i<laserScan.size();i++){    
    newDouble.SetDouble(laserScan[i]);
    const char* index = std::to_string(i).c_str();
    size = (rapidjson::SizeType)std::strlen(index);
    newStringIndex.SetString(rapidjson::StringRef(index,size));
    d.AddMember(newStringIndex,newDouble,d.GetAllocator());
}
```

This throws the following run-time error from Writer class:

```
Assertion `!hasRoot_' failed.
```

**Why I'm Confused**

Shouldn't solution #1 be the same thing as doing the following?

```
d.AddMember("1",newDouble,d.GetAllocator());
```

This works when I try it, but I can't figure out why converting an integer to a const char* won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. Instead of making all the keys integers, I just added the key "indices" with the corresponding value being an array of all the indices. Then I added another array called "data" which contained an array of all the data:

```
rapidjson::Document document;
rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = document.GetAllocator();
rapidjson::Value dataArray(rapidjson::kArrayType), ;

for(int i = 0;i<laserScan.size();i++){                 
    dataArray.PushBack(rapidjson::Value().SetDouble(laserScan[i]),allocator);
}
document.AddMember("data",dataArrary,allocator);
```

Comment: Thanks [Milo Yip](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1018640/milo-yip) for the documentation - took a few lines from the tutorials page to make the fix.

Answer (score 8):

Although you have already find an workaround, I would like to state why the original solution is not working.

The problem of solution #1 is that, the `index` pointer is invalid when exiting the scope.

As stated in [tutorial](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#ModifyObject), you can create a key string with allocator to make a copy of it:

```
std::string s = std::to_string(i)
Value index(s.c_str(), s.size(), d.GetAllocator()); // copy string
d.AddMember(index, newDouble, d.GetAllocator());
```

And for your workaround, you can simply:

```
dataArray.PushBack(laserScan[i], allocator);
```